# What does "the orchestra broke out" mean?

Tags: short-stories, meaning, p-g-wodehouse

The short story *[The Man, the Maid and the Miasma](http://www.classicreader.com/book/3383/1/)* by P.G. Wodehouse ends with the following paragraphs:

> He bent across the table.
>
> 'Isn't this like the old times?' he said. 'Do you remember the first time I ever ki–'
>
> Just then the orchestra broke out.

The sentence I am wondering about is the last, "Just then the orchestra broke out". My first thought was that it was all a play in the theatre, because there were a few references to the theater in the story. Am I right, or is there a better explanation?

Comment: Without more context...hard to say. But isn´t it possible they were in a restaurant and the orchestra _started up and began to play_?

Comment: @Cascabel: *Hard to say?* I'd have thought any meaning other than the one you suggested would require a ridiculously contrived context. *The conductor decided he couldn't trust the orchestra to play John Cage's 4′33″ correctly, so he locked them all in the dressing-room. After conducting the piece "note perfect" for four and a half minutes he was feverishly anticipating thunderous applause for his performance. **Just then the orchestra** [smashed the dressing-room door and] **broke out**, making so much noise he abandoned any attempts to finish properly.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers I didn´t want to discount the possibility...or perhaps they were dining at the local hoosegow and the band was locked up for playing off-key...

Comment: Here's the context: https://books.google.ae/books?id=nPAGAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT165&lpg=PT165&dq=Just+then+the+orchestra+broke+out.&source=bl&ots=289bXeJlQO&sig=RW5lX4rGoZX-13NmRe0VyD_wldM&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Just%20then%20the%20orchestra%20broke%20out.&f=false

Comment: Obviously, it was an orchestra of teenagers and they all broke out in pimples simultaneously.

Comment: Migrated to Literature from EL&U at this community's request.

Answer (score 9):

They are having supper in a place with an orchestra - possibly a night club. This is mentioned earlier in the story:

> 'As a matter of fact,' he said, haughtily, 'I was to have had supper
> with a chorus-girl this very night.'

The orchestra is getting ready to play:

> 'Bob,' said the girl, as the first threatening mutters from the
> orchestra heralded an imminent storm of melody, …

Note the comparison to a **storm**.

> **[break out](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/break+out)**
>
> 1. to burst forth suddenly, as with a fire, a riot, giggling, shouting, etc. *A fire broke out in the belfry. A round of giggling
>    broke out when the teacher tripped.*

---

> [**a storm breaks (=begins):**](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/storm_1)
>
> *A violent storm broke just as we reached the mountain.*

Answer (score 4):

**Break out** in the dictionary means:

> to develop or emerge with suddenness or force  [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/break%20out)

Some examples given are *the fire broke out* or *the riot broke out*, meaning, suddenly began.

So in this case, 'the orchestra broke out' means 'suddenly started playing'.